# Handle Identity API Scope Approval UI with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing UI tests (Selenium, Java) against a Google Chrome extension. The Google Chrome extension permits external logins/sign-ups (Google, Microsoft). Once the **Login** button is clicked in the extension, a new window is opened, namely **Identity API Scope Approval UI**, which cannot be found using `driver.getWindowHandles();`. Via the handles a new `Confirm Permission` window is found with the following content:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scope_approval_dialog.css">
    <script src="scope_approval_dialog.js"></script>
    <title>Confirm Permission</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="titlebar titlebar-border">
        <span class="titlebar-close-button"></span>
    </div>
    <webview class="content" id="providerview" src="..."></webview>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea how to get in touch with that **Identity API Scope Approval UI** and to perform Selenium actions on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to inject js code into your browser in order to interact with the webview. Basically once you switch to the correct window of the Identity API UI with the driver as you have done, you're going to inject js like so:

`document.querySelector("webview").executeScript({code: "document.querySelector(\"input[name='login']\").value = 'username'"})`

If you're using the wrapper Selenide, you can use `Selenide.executeJavaScript(code)` to do this, otherwise with vanilla Selenium you have to use the `JavaScriptExecutor` class. (I highly recommend checking out Selenide though.

So `executeJavaScript("document.querySelector(\"webview\").executeScript({code: \"document.querySelector(\\\"SELECTOR_HERE\\\").value = 'VALUE_HERE'\"})")`

Remember to escape any necessary characters, I know this is escape character  hell.

Late answer, but hope this helps anyone that might be having this issue.